# make qemu on xv6-riscv gets stucked at qemu-system-riscv64 ... command

Tags: xv6

On Ubuntu 20.04, I installed the xv6 project using the page [Tools Used in 6.828](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2019/tools.html)

```
$ sudo apt-get install git build-essential gdb-multiarch qemu-system-misc gcc-riscv64-linux-gnu binutils-riscv64-linux-gnu
```

The file version that they checked on the web page are

```
$ riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc --version 
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc () 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ qemu-system-riscv64 --version
QEMU emulator version 5.2.50 (v5.2.0-2349-g51db2d7cf2)
Copyright (c) 2003-2020 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
```

On xv6-riscv

```
$ make qemu
# ... lots of output ...
qemu-system-riscv64 -machine virt -bios none -kernel kernel/kernel -m 128M -smp 3 -nographic -drive file=fs.img,if=none,format=raw,id=x0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=x0,bus=virtio-mmio-bus.0
```

The program get stuck there. The vm is not booted and no prompt is shown.

Any ideas on how to fix this are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been mentioned in [Tools Used in 6.S081](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.S081/2020/tools.html)

> At this moment in time, it seems that the package qemu-system-misc has received an
> update that breaks its compatibility with our kernel. If you run make qemu and the
> script appears to hang after
>
> ```sh
> qemu-system-riscv64 -machine virt -bios none -kernel kernel/kernel -m 128M -smp 3 
> nographic -drive file=fs.img,if=none,format=raw,id=x0 -device virtio-blk
> device,drive=x0,bus=virtio-mmio-bus.0
> ```
>
> you'll need to uninstall that package and install an older version:
>
> ```sh
> $ sudo apt-get remove qemu-system-misc
> $ sudo apt-get install qemu-system-misc=1:4.2-3ubuntu6
> ```

Comment: But I met the error that it couldn't find version `1:4.2-3ubuntu6` of `qemu-system-misc` on Ubuntu 18.04.5. Hope for helps.

Comment: I've just posted a [question related to the problem above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66718225/qemu-system-riscv64-is-not-found-in-package-qemu-system-misc).

Comment: Ohhhh I found the solution X)

Answer (score 1):

Code issue, pulling the 2020 version of XV6 code may cause this issue. My solution is to switch to a newer version of the code, such as the 2021 and 2022 versions,

```
git clone git://g.csail.mit.edu/xv6-labs-2021
```