# qemu-system-riscv64 is not found in package qemu-system-misc

Tags: qemu, xv6

I'm trying to set up xv6 on Ubuntu 18.04.5 but there is an error during `make qemu`:

```sh
# outputs...
qemu-system-riscv64 -machine virt -bios none -kernel kernel/kernel -m 128M -smp 3 -nographic -drive file=fs.img,if=none,format=raw,id=x0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=x0,bus=virtio-mmio-bus.0
make: qemu-system-riscv64: Command not found
```

I found that there is no `qemu-system-riscv64` under `/usr/bin` after installing `qemu-system-misc`(version 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.36):

```sh
$ ls /usr/bin | grep qemu
qemu-img
qemu-io
qemu-nbd
qemu-system-alpha
qemu-system-cris
qemu-system-lm32
qemu-system-m68k
qemu-system-microblaze
qemu-system-microblazeel
qemu-system-moxie
qemu-system-nios2
qemu-system-or1k
qemu-system-sh4
qemu-system-sh4eb
qemu-system-tricore
qemu-system-unicore32
qemu-system-xtensa
qemu-system-xtensaeb
```

I've tried to install an older version of `qemu-system-misc` which is mentioned in [Tools Used in 6.S081](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.S081/2020/tools.html)

> At this moment in time, it seems that the package qemu-system-misc has received an
> update that breaks its compatibility with our kernel. If you run make qemu and the
> script appears to hang after
>
> ```sh
> qemu-system-riscv64 -machine virt -bios none -kernel kernel/kernel -m 128M -smp 3 nographic -drive file=fs.img,if=none,format=raw,id=x0 -device virtio-blk device,drive=x0,bus=virtio-mmio-bus.0
> ```
>
> you'll need to uninstall that package and install an older version:
>
> ```sh
> $ sudo apt-get remove qemu-system-misc
> $ sudo apt-get install qemu-system-misc=1:4.2-3ubuntu6
> ```

yet this version was not found.

Any solution for installing either `qemu-system-riscv64` or an older version of `qemu-system-misc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything went right after I [upgraded Ubuntu](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/upgrade-ubuntu-16-04-to-ubuntu-18-04) to version 20.04.2 :)

Answer (score 2):

Refer https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2020/tools.html

You can compile qemu

```
$ wget https://download.qemu.org/qemu-5.1.0.tar.xz
$ tar xf qemu-5.1.0.tar.xz


$ cd qemu-5.1.0
$ ./configure --disable-kvm --disable-werror --prefix=/usr/local --target-list="riscv64-softmmu"
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ cd ..
```